# Enabling feature specific property in Karate

Tags: automation, karate

I have a use-case where i need to have a feature specific properties. 
For example I need to set the readTimeout values as common for all the execution but for one specific feature, i need to have the custom value.
Kindly advise.

Adding it in karate config file will implement for all the feature file, guide me to have custom value for specific/single feature file.

Example :  karate.configure('readTimeout', 10000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do / over-ride this in a feature like this:

```
* configure readTimeout = 10000
```

Kindly refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure